# Storyboard UITableViewController enable toolbar at bottom of screen

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created a storyboard based `UITableViewController` which is working and displaying data.

I now need to add a toolbar that will always be at the bottom of the screen. To do this I have added a toolbar button to my storyboard which has it positioned at the bottom of the screen.

I have added the following to my tableviewcontrollers viewWillAppear method

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

As described here
[How to add a toolbar to the bottom of a UITableViewController in Storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625416/how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-the-bottom-of-a-uitableviewcontroller-in-storyboards)

However, I still get no toolbar...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want show toolbar in one view controller which placed in some navigation controller.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//View will appear
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
//View will disappear
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: ok so must use a navigation controller with my tableviewcontroller?

Comment: tableviewcontroller has navigationcontroller in it.