# Floating Media Controlls on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, robovm

I am converting a radio app that I made for Android to iOS. The apps MUST be as uniform as possible in their design. On Android I use fragments to create a media controller with a play/pause button and a seek bar that is on the bottom of all screens of the app. I would like to create a similar effect on iOS.

[image: android]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a toolbar to the bottom of a UITableViewController in Storyboards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625416/how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-the-bottom-of-a-uitableviewcontroller-in-storyboards)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is painstakingly obvious. I added a bottom bar to the view.

See:
 [How to add a toolbar to the bottom of a UITableViewController in Storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625416/how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-the-bottom-of-a-uitableviewcontroller-in-storyboards)